# What weapon type deals the most against vampires in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

All this time, I thought silver does more damage to vampires. Turns out that's not the case. What does then?

Comment: According to [Wikia](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Silver_Weapons_(Skyrim)), Silver weapons do more damage to vampires: `If one has the most recent patch (1.9.32.0.8), silver weapons also apply their bonus damage against Vampires.`. This bonus damage is 20 extra base damage

Comment: Oh, I was just reading that page awhile ago and for some reason I missed that line at the end, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Silver is for werewolves.
Fire spells and weapons with fire enchantments are most efficient against vampires.

This is because vampires have a 50% weakness to fire damage (opposed to a 50% resistance to frost damage)

Source: [Skyrim wiki/Vampire page](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Vampire_%28Skyrim%29)

Comment: Thanks! @Mathias711 clarified that as of 1.9.32.0.8, they also deal the bonus damage against vampires. Time to find myself a fire-enchanted silver sword (heh).

Comment: @user400424 One of my higher priorities in Skyrim is going to Ironbind Barrow and learning the Fiery Soul Trap Enchant.  10 points of fire damage per hit *and* fills soul gems.  You also get a relatively high number of hits for the soul power.

Answer (score 0):

A Smithy enhanced bow/sword with fire enchantments works great.  I got some great weapons from Oblivion, Ebony Bow/Sword, and upgraded them at Smith with ebony ingots.  Bow deals 102 base damage now, (Legendary upgrade), and sword is 58.  Both called "of the inferno," they also do 45% fire damage.  Wicked.  Add ebony arrows and if you have archery perks, and enchanted armor for more archery damage (Eleven Bracers of Eminent Archery), Bows do an extra 35% damage.  Drink archery potion, and it's a one shot deal...for most levels of Vampires...perhaps two on really bad guys.